# Alexa Skill : How to invoke custom intent from a template?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an alexa skill with the help of 'Survey' template, which uses personalization + voice recognition based auth.

personalization + voice recognition based auth works fine. I have added a new intent 'Introduce' which needs to be triggered based on utterance - 'introduce' but that isn't working as expected.

1. Alexa open my bot
   -> (welcome note from alexa)
2. let's begin (invokes StartMyStandupIntentHandler intent and auth based on voice id)
   -> Hello  How can i help you?
3. introduce
   -> doesn't invoke IntroduceHandler but i have IntentReflectorHandler that says : You just triggered the introduce intent. You're hearing this response because introduce does not have an intent handler yet.

index.js:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();

    const skillName = requestAttributes.t('SKILL_NAME');
    const name = personalization.getPersonalizedPrompt(handlerInput);
    var speakOutput = ""
    if (name && name.length > 0) {
        speakOutput = requestAttributes.t('GREETING_PERSONALIZED', skillName);
    } else {
        speakOutput = requestAttributes.t('GREETING', skillName);
    }
    const repromptOutput = requestAttributes.t('GREETING_REPROMPT');

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speakOutput)
      .reprompt(repromptOutput)
      .getResponse();
  },
};


const StartMyStandupIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'StartMyStandupIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    let speakOutput;
    const name = personalization.getPersonalizedPrompt(handlerInput);
    let response = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    if (name && name.length > 0) {
        speakOutput = 'Hello '+ name +'! How can i help you?';
        const upsServiceClient = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
        let profileName
        let profileEmail
        try {
            profileName = await upsServiceClient.getPersonsProfileGivenName();
            profileEmail = await upsServiceClient.getProfileEmail();
        } catch (error) {
            return handleError(error, handlerInput)
        }

        const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        sessionAttributes.userEmail = profileEmail;
        sessionAttributes.userName = profileName;
        handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);
    } else {
      speakOutput = requestAttributes.t('PERSONALIZED_FALLBACK')
    }
    return response
      .speak(speakOutput)
      .withShouldEndSession(false)
      .getResponse()
  },
};

const Introduce_Handler  =  {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'Introduce'
    },
     handle(handlerInput) {
        const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;

        let say = 'Hi everyone, As the famous saying goes,  \'The human voice is the most perfect instrument of all\', . ';
        say += 'A very Warm greetings to all. ';

        return responseBuilder
            .speak(say)
            .withShouldEndSession(false)
            .getResponse();
    },
};

/**
 * Voice consent request - response is handled via Skill Connections.
 * Hence we need to handle async response from the Voice Consent.
 * The user could have accepted or rejected or skipped the voice consent request.
 * Create your custom callBackFunction to handle accepted flow - in this case its handling identifying the person
 * The rejected/skipped default handling is taken care by the library.
 *
 * @params handlerInput - the handlerInput received from the IntentRequest
 * @returns
 **/
async function handleCallBackForVoiceConsentAccepted(handlerInput) {
    const upsServiceClient = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
    let profileName = await upsServiceClient.getProfileEmail();
    let profileEmail = await upsServiceClient.getPersonsProfileGivenName();
    const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    sessionAttributes.userEmail = profileEmail;
    sessionAttributes.userName = profileName;
    handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);

    // this is done because currently intent chaining is not supported from any
    // Skill Connections requests, such as SessionResumedRequest.
    const requestAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    const name = personalization.getPersonalizedPrompt(handlerInput);
    let speakOutput = 'Hello '+ name +'! How can i help you?';
    //let repromptOutput = requestAttributes.t('ABOUT_REPROMPT');

    let response = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
    return response
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .getResponse()
}
```

Interaction model json:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "my bot",
            "modelConfiguration": {
                "fallbackIntentSensitivity": {
                    "level": "LOW"
                }
            },
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "GetCodeIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "MeetingCode",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "My code is {MeetingCode}",
                        "The code is {MeetingCode}",
                        "{MeetingCode}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "GetReportIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "questionYesterday",
                            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                            "samples": [
                                "{questionYesterday}"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "questionToday",
                            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                            "samples": [
                                "{questionToday}"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "questionBlocking",
                            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                            "samples": [
                                "{questionBlocking}"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{questionToday} today",
                        "{questionYesterday} yesterday",
                        "yesterday {questionYesterday}",
                        "today {questionToday}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.YesIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NoIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "ResetPinIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "where do i get a pin",
                        "what is my pin",
                        "how do i get a pin",
                        "i need a new pin",
                        "i forgot my pin"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "StartMyStandupIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "yes let's get started",
                        "yes let's begin",
                        "let's begin",
                        "let's get started"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Introduce",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "introduce yourself",
                        "introduce",
                        "intro"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        },
        "dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "GetReportIntent",
                    "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "questionYesterday",
                            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.420907304064.1434077833163"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "questionToday",
                            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.173201382582.539843571833"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "questionBlocking",
                            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.173201382582.1204298947985"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
        },
        "prompts": [
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.288779318596.409557698368",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Alright, first question. What did you do yesterday?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.288779318596.1420775370020",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Got it. What will you do today?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.288779318596.88143460540",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Okay, last question. Is there anything blocking your progress?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.420907304064.1434077833163",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "What did you work on yesterday?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.173201382582.539843571833",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "What will you work on today?"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.173201382582.1204298947985",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "What if anything is blocking your progress?"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you missed adding your intent handler to the Skill object. See this snipet from the [Alexa documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/develop-your-first-skill.html#lambdahandler)

```
let skill;

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  console.log(`REQUEST++++${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  if (!skill) {
    skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
      .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        StartMyStandupIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
      )
      .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
      .create();
  }

  const response = await skill.invoke(event, context);
  console.log(`RESPONSE++++${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

  return response;
};
```

You need to add the `Introduce_Handler` to the `addRequestHandlers` method call. Also, make sure to add it **before** the intent reflector handler. ASK will prioritize which handler is used based on the order they are added to the skill object. Your code will probably look something like this:

```
.addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        AskWeatherIntentHandler,
        Introduce_Handler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        IntentReflectorHandler 
      )
```